# IPC message queue. msgrcv system call. System V. how to get out of loop

Tags: c, message-queue, shared-memory, msgrcv, msgsend

I have a message queue from which I am getting messages in a loop. The problem is that I don't know how to exit the loop. msgrcv returns type size_t so it keeps going. What value should I compare the return value so I can exit the loop?

```
while(msgrcv(msqid, &msgreceived, sizeof(msgreceived), BUFFER_CHANGED, 0) != -1){
    printf("%d %d %d %d ",msgreceived.value0,msgreceived.value1,msgreceived.value2,msgreceived.value3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your last parameter does not include `IPC_NOWAIT`, `msgrcv` blocks while waiting for future messages.

If there is no message to be read immediately, `msgrcv(..., ... | IPC_NOWAIT)` will return `(size_t)-1` and set `errno = ENOMSG`.